# Upgraded to iOS 9.0.1 and lost all health weight data

Tags: ios, health.app

I just upgraded my iPhone (model MG5D2LL/A) to iOS 9.0.1 yesterday, and I did one backup restore to resolve an issue with the Podcast app (still not resolved).

I lost most of my Health app data. I lost all of my manually entered weight data (several years worth) and my Medical ID. For some reason the dashboard is still showing the last 7 days of steps, walking, climbing data.

Is there any way to recover that data?

Comment: Was your backup encrypted? Without an encrypted iTunes backup, passwords & health data are not saved.

Comment: It wasn't, thanks for the info. So the info was wiped out (replaced by "empty info") during the backup?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, sorry - I only made that mistake on my first ever iPhone, a long long time ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backups don't backup health data unless they're encrypted backups.

Thus, if you restore one of these unencrypted backups, you won't restore the health data. This data is gone—it's not stored in iCloud for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me this morning. Switching phone off and back on seems to have done the trick.

Comment: My backup was encrypted. My data disappeared during 9.0.1 update. Switching phone off and back on also worked for me.